# SQL Server 2008 R2 FILESTREAM using ASP.NET & Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, filestream

I have been searching now for 2 days and still struggling! Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

I am busy creating a web app - an online vehicle trader project.

Tech: VS2010, SQL Server 2008 R2, Entity Data Model 4 (EF), SQL Filestream For Images.

I have my filestream setup correctly and can upload and download images (`varbinary(MAX)`).

My problems/questions are:

1. I have link in a data grid that will download the image. I don't want to download, I need to display the actual image in the grid.
2. All of the above is done using ADO.NET, how can this be integrated into EF? My understanding is that EF does NOT support filestream? Has this changed in EF4?

Maybe I have this whole thing backwards?

Any advise, links to examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of FILESTREAM support in EF yet but I don't think you really need it. You can just map the ID of the image in EF and use plain SQL to load the image content in the browser. This will not be a problem because you never load to eagerly load the image in a web app as it is rendered via a separate URL so you only need the ID. The SQL to fetch something by ID is the simplest thing ever so you don't lose any of the EF power. The only problem may be eventual inserts if you have FKs that are related to EF objects but this should be simple enough.